# getting unsatisfied entitlements

Tags: macos, provisioning-profile, entitlements, ios-app-group

When I'm starting my MacOS app, I can see at the console the errors

```
 com.myAppBundle: Unsatisfied entitlements: com.apple.security.application-groups 
 Disallowing: com.myAppBundle
```

However, it's seems that the app is working just fine,
and I do have entitlements files with those values:

```
<key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
<key>com.apple.security.application-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>$(TeamIdentifierPrefix)group</string>
    </array>
```

So why I'm getting the "Unsatisfied entitlements" error ?

Edit:

For iOS apps, in addition to the capabilities tab, one need to add App Groups at Apple Developer account.
But there is no such option for OSX apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old question but since it got some upvotes recently, I'll add some info that might help:
on macOS the app group identifier is prefixed by the Team ID, whereas that’s not the case on iOS.

So for iOS the app group can be something like:
group.com.example.aaaa.bbb

and for macOS:
V123ABC4ER.com.example.aaa.bbb